# Beginner question: finding correlations with percentage data

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance

I am trying to work out whether mobile, desktop or tablet users are more likely to perform an action on a site.

The data I have is structured as follows:

```
week     clicked      mobile    tablet    desktop
1        1            104       97        205
1        0            204       214       348
2        1            128       108       257
2        0            207       222       360
```

... though I have about 25 weeks' worth and the numbers are larger! I can munge the data and restructure it if needed (e.g. into percentages) but that is the structure of the raw data.

I am relatively new to statistics and trying to educate myself and ensure the approach I take is valid and meaningful.

My null hypothesis is "the type of device used makes no difference to the outcome", but I'd like to investigate whether that's not the case.

What would be a valid statistical test to use in this scenario? I'm working in R, can also use pandas.

Any advice gratefully appreciated.

UPDATE: The research I've done suggests that I should restructure this into rows for mobile, desktop and tablet, with the percentage conversion for each row, and then conduct a chi-squared test. Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Are you willing to ignore the time nature of the data, or is it important?

Comment: Thank you @PeterFlom! The time nature of the data isn't particularly important, so I'd be willing to ignore it.

Comment: chi-squared sounds reasonable. be aware that if you have lots of data even small differences from equal proportions can be 'statistically significant' - this may not be what you are after though. something else you might look at is eg. Jeffreys interval, which would give you confidence intervals on the separate proportions.  This might be easier to interpret.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval

Answer (score 1):

If you ignore the time nature of the data then the method that springs to mind is logistic regression with the dependent variable being whether the person clicked and the independent variable being type of device.